# Font in Shopify Store does not load

Tags: html, css, fonts, shopify

Hello thank you very much in Advance,

i am customizing a Shopify Store for my Sister and I need to add a new Font to the Store. I searched for some guides and tried it in my Test Store.

I Uploaded a new Asset which was a Font in woff2 format, inserted the code line from the Shopify.dev site on the base.css file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Font name";
  src: url({{ [font-file-name] | asset_url }}) format("[font-format]");
}
```

also i defined on which Headline the Font should be applied to.

It worked, now I want to apply it to the actual store but noticed the Font isn't loading anymore.

I tried different things for 3 Hours but couldn't find the solution.

The Font isn't available via Google Fonts or Adobe Typekit already looked for that.

Comment: Could be possible that you're missing the "? It should be `src: url("{{...}}")`

Comment: I tried that, but this doesn't change anything. Thank you tho!

Comment: @ChikenJoe I had a similar problem a while ago and solved it by removing `format()` when only one format is provided. Can't explain why it worked but it's worth a shot I guess